# Easiest drive imaging solution

Tags: windows-7, clone

Recently my Win7 installation on my SSD went corrupt :(

Now I have to reinstall everything from scratch.

My SSD is 256GB and I took out my optical drive (its a laptop) and put in another hdd of 500gb that is partitioned as 200/200/100 of which I have cleared everything off the first 200 partition.

Can anyone recommend a imaging solution for a total newbie that I can image the 256GB SSD onto the 200GB backup? Most of what I have been googling say you must have a backup at the same size as the drive you want to make the image of or larger :(

Please note I have never done a drive image before so it should be simple.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't Win7 have the ability to image drives built-in?

Comment: I dont know... :( does it?

Comment: Yes, apparently it does. See [quickly create a hard drive image in Windows 7](http://windows7themes.net/how-to-create-hard-drive-image-in-windows-7.html).

Comment: Here's another article you might find useful titled [The Best Articles for Backing Up and Syncing Your Data](http://www.howtogeek.com/108679/the-best-articles-for-backing-up-and-syncing-your-data/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [DriveImageXML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm). The private edition is free and I've made good experiences with this software. The image only needs the used space and not the complete space of the partition.

Answer (score 2):

[Acronis TrueImage](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/index.html) is super easy to use. It can image your drive while you're using your computer, compresses the image by default, and lets you schedule automatic full, incremental, or differential backups.

MSRP is $49, but the full version usually sells online for half that, or even 90% off if you're into rebates.

As for your Windows corruption issue, firmware bugs are notorious for causing data loss on SSDs. You may want to see if there is a firmware update available for your SSD, and install it after you've imaged the drive.